# Java Android: how to parse intent data to JSOn format?

Tags: java, android, ionic-framework

I have an issue with converting bundle into JSON. Here is my code:

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
JSONObject object_example = new JSONObject( extras.getString("data"));
String message = object_example.getString("alert");
```

And when I am trying to compile with ionic, I get the following error:

```
Users/Lukasz/xxxx/platforms/android/src/com/plugin/gcm/GCMIntentService.java:73: error: unreported exception JSONException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
        JSONObject object_example = new JSONObject( extras.getString("data"));
                                    ^
/Users/Lukasz/xxxx/platforms/android/src/com/plugin/gcm/GCMIntentService.java:74: error: unreported exception JSONException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
        String message = object_example.getString("alert");
                                                 ^
```

What am I doing wrong :)?

Thanks!

Comment: log your full json, understand it then try to parse, or post that in your question

Comment: Maybe use a try catch block to catch the JSONException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the method should throw `JsonException` in the defination or you must use `try catch` to catch `JsonException` if you want to use `JSONObject`. But it still unclear until you post you full log and your code.

Answer (score 0):

String answers_json = data.getExtras().getString("answers");
                Answers.AllValue hasil = (Answers.AllValue) data.getSerializableExtra(SurveyActivity.ANSWERSOBJECT);

```
            Log.e("ANSWERS JSON", answers_json);
```

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks